# vim vundle plugin - PluginInstall fail on every plugin - gvim 74 under windows 7

Tags: vim, plugins, windows-7

As title says, I have finally got it all set up and when I start my vim I get no troubles. But when I run the command to install plugins, its error after error and nothing happens. I followed the exact instructions provided to install vundle. Help is appreciated.

```
" Plugins -----------------------------------------------------------------
" set up vundle to handle plugins
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/vimfiles/bundle/Vundle.vim
let path='~/vimfiles/bundle'
call vundle#begin(path)

" :PluginList - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean  - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
" :h vundle for more details

Plugin 'gmarik/vundle.vim'              " easily install and update vim plugins
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'             " cool git wrapper
Plugin 'L9'
Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim'}  "script in a subdirectory
Plugin 'user/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}     " avoid name conflict with L9
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'               " Easyily manipulate surrounding tags
"Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree.git'    " directory explorer for vim
"Plugin 'Buffergator'                " list,select and switch between buffers
""Plugin 'Lokaltog/vim-powerline'         " A status line plugin for vim
"Plugin 'vim-addon-mw-utils'         " snipmate depends on this
"Plugin 'tlib_vim'                   " snipmate depends on this
"Plugin 'snipMate'                   " Snippet/boilerplate tool
"Plugin 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion'    " A simplification of vim motions
"Plugin 'matchit.zip'                " Extends % to more than just braces
"Plugin 'Alternate-workspace'        " switch between header/code files
"Plugin 'tComment'                   " easily toggle comments
"Plugin 'MRU'                        " show ten most recent files
"Plugin 'rainbow_parentheses.vim'
call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on

" setup powerline for vim #start
python from powerline.vim import setup as powerline_setup
python powerline_setup()
python del powerline_setup

set laststatus=2
set guifont=Inconsolata\ for\ Powerline:h12
" setup powerline for vim #stop
```

The error messages I get are all along the lines of this example, which I grabbed from its attempt to install fugitive.

Processing 'tpope/vim-fugitive'

```
Error detected while processing function vundle#installer#new..<SNR>30_process..
vundle#installer#run..vundle#installer#install..<SNR>30_syn..<SNR>30_system:
line  1:
E484: Can't open file C:/Users/%MYUSERNAME%/AppData/Local/Temp/VIo7A20.tmp
Error detected while processing function vundle#installer#new..<SNR>30_process:
line  13:
E121: Undefined variable: s:last_status
E15: Invalid expression: 'error s:last_status
line  17:
E121: Undefined variable: s:last_status
E15: Invalid expression: 'updated' == s:last_status && empty(msg)
```

Still haven't got plugins working. Help is appreciated

Comment: Did you follow this? https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim/wiki/Vundle-for-Windows, you need to change the path for the bundle directory

Comment: I followed that. I will add the whole Plugins section of my vimrc to the question

Comment: What is the error message? Also remove all the plugins you aren't using. I doubt the `L9` (local) plugin is something you are going to use.

Comment: I'll give the example when it is processing tim popes fugitive. Also I have commented out the L9 thing, not sure that is anyway, I only just started setting up vim in my windows environment so i commented out most of the things i had before. The L9 plugin was from following the guide on github. 

I will add the error to the question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on vim 7.4 with Windows 7, while running the bug.n tiling window manager. I just closed bug.n and magically it worked.
BTW: bug.n uses autohotkey.